# Is there better way to use wait/notify with connection with AtomicInteger

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, wait, notify

I've this kind of code:

```
public class RecursiveQueue {
    //@Inject
    private QueueService queueService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecursiveQueue test = new RecursiveQueue();
        test.enqueue(new Node("X"), true);
        test.enqueue(new Node("Y"), false);
        test.enqueue(new Node("Z"), false);
    }

    private void enqueue(final Node node, final boolean waitTillFinished) {
        final AtomicLong totalDuration = new AtomicLong(0L);
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        AfterCallback callback= new AfterCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish(Result result) {
                for(Node aNode : result.getChildren())  {
                    counter.incrementAndGet();
                    queueService.requestProcess(aNode, this);
                }

                totalDuration.addAndGet(result.getDuration());
                if(counter.decrementAndGet() <= 0) { //last one
                    System.out.println("Processing of " + node.toString() + " has finished in " + totalDuration.get() + " ms");
                    if(waitTillFinished) {
                        counter.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        counter.incrementAndGet();
        queueService.requestProcess(node, callback);
        if(waitTillFinished) {
            try {
                counter.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Imagine there is a `queueService` which uses blocking queue and few consumer threads to process nodes = calls DAO to fetch children of nodes (it's a tree).
So `requestProcess` method just enqueues the node and does not block.

Is there some better/safe way to avoid using wait/notify in this sample ?
According to some findings I can use Phaser (but I work on java 6) or conditions (but I'm not using locks).

Answer (score 3):

- There is no `synchronized` anything in your example.  You mustn't call `o.wait()` or `o.notify()` except from within a `synchronized(o) {...}` block.
- Your call to `wait()` is not in a loop.  This may not ever happen in your JVM, but the language spec permits `wait()` to return prematurely (that's known as a *spurious wakeup*)  More generally, it is good practice to always use a loop because it's a familiar design pattern.  A `while` statement costs no more than an `if`, and you *should* have it because of the possibility of spurious wakeup, and you'd absolutely *must* have it in a multi-consumer situation, and so you might as well just always write it that way.
- Since you must use `synchronized` blocks in order to use `wait()` and `notify()`, there probably is no reason to use `Atomic` anything.
- This "recursive" thing seems awfully complicated, what with the callback adding more items to the queue.  How deep can that go?

Comment: Thanks, this seems that almost answered question. The tree has maximal depth of 5 or something like that. This queue is processing "requests" from various sources and there is no need to return immediately (it's used for loading data into temporary cache for future usage. 
Yes, I forgot to write `wait/notify` properly (I wrote that quickly). 
So is there way to do that in Java 6, without `synchronized` blocks and without low level `wait/notify` or I better do that ?

Comment: @czs, Sorry, but there's not enough information in your question.  Synchronization is all about protecting _shared data_ from corruption when two or more threads operate on it at the same time.  Your example is a stand-alone demo that does not create any new threads.  You would have to modify it to use the code in any other program.  What would that other program look like?  What threads would share data?  What data would they share?  What is a `QueueService`? What does `requestProcess(...)` do?  What _problem_ are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: Not really as it requires upfront knowledge of nodes to be processed and this knowledge could be obtained only by processing parent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You actually use locks or, let's put it this way, you should be using them if you try to use wait/notify as James pointed out. As you are bound to Java 1.6 and ForkJoin or Phaser are not available to you the choice is either implementing wait/notify properly or using Condition with explicit lock. This would be a matter of your personal preferences.

Another alternative is to try and restructure your algorithm so you first get to know the entire set of steps you would need to execute. It is not always possible though.